# Copying all entries from one table to another with a hard coded value

Tags: mysql

I currently am copying multiple tables from different mysql schemas  into 1 table.  While trying to copy all of the entries, I am having issues with the "Insert" into temp table.

cua010.doc_table

> | ID | _FilePath |

testing.temp_entries

> | ID | File | Schema |

Here is my query

```
INSERT INTO testing.temp_entries (File, Schema )
SELECT _FilePath, 'CU010'
FROM cua010.doc_table
```

In the end I would like to results to be

> | ID | File | Schema |
>
> | 1  | test | cua010 |
>
> | 2  | test2| cua010 |...

This is the error message i get

> 0 84  14:49:47    INSERT INTO testing.temp_entries (File, Schema )
> SELECT _FilePath, 'cua010'
> FROM cua010.doc_table    Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for
> the right syntax to use near 'Schema)
> SELECT _FilePath, 'cua010'
> FROM cua010.doc_table' at line 1   0.031 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "`" around schema  (alt +96 in windows)

```
 INSERT INTO testing.temp_entries (File, `Schema` ) 
  SELECT _FilePath, 'cua010' 
  FROM cua010.doc_table ;
```

Comment: schema is a KEYWORD and you must escape it with back ticks `schema`

Comment: I suggested use of  proper quotes " ` " for this

Answer (score 1):

Schema is a reserved word.

```
INSERT INTO `testing`.`temp_entries` (`File`, `Schema` )
SELECT `_FilePath`, 'CU010'
FROM `cua010`.`doc_table`
```